# Showing the number in front of an inline citation with \bibentry

Tags: latex, bibliography

I would like to show the number in front of the full inline citation generated by `\bibentry` from the `bibentry` package, matching the one that appears in the bibliography.

In the following MWE, this would correspond to a [2] in front of the indented `\bibentry`. How would I do that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{Emma,
author = "Emma",
title = "Emma's publication",
year = "2001" }
@misc{Martha,
author = "Martha",
title = "Interesting thoughts",
year = "2003" }
@misc{Paul,
author = "Paul",
title = "Paul's essay",
year = "2000" }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nobibliography*
\noindent
This is a usual reference~\cite{Emma}.
Now I'm referring to\\[5pt]
\indent \bibentry{Martha}.\\[5pt]
The following is again a normal reference~\cite{Paul}.
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[This image shows the output of the above MWE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHtBv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `bibentry` doesn't allow that, one possible solution is to define a new command (or redefine `\bibentry`) as a `\cite` and `\bibentry`.

Some thing like that:

```latex
\let\oldbibentry\bibentry
\renewcommand{\bibentry}[1]{\cite{#1} \oldbibentry{#1}}
```

So if we try this code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}

% redefine the bibentry command as cite then bibentry
\let\oldbibentry\bibentry
\renewcommand{\bibentry}[1]{\cite{#1} \oldbibentry{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{Emma,
author = "Emma",
title = "Emma's publication",
year = "2001" }
@misc{Martha,
author = "Martha",
title = "Interesting thoughts",
year = "2003" }
@misc{Paul,
author = "Paul",
title = "Paul's essay",
year = "2000" }
\end{filecontents}
\nobibliography*
\begin{document}
\noindent
This is a usual reference~\cite{Emma}.
Now I'm referring to\\[5pt]
\indent \bibentry{Martha}.\\[5pt]
The following is again a normal reference~\cite{Paul}.
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

it should produce:
[image]

Comment: Beautiful. It's obvious, really, but didn't come to my mind. Thanks!